# Spring Logs cannot be viewed in console or log file(Application deployed in WAS)

Tags: apache, logging, websphere

Ok, I'm stuck up with this for a week now. I'm unable to view the spring logs/castor logs in WAS console or the log file. 
I'm able to do the same in Tomcat. I have tried most of the things by searching online. But nothing helped.
I use IBM WAS-7.0.0.11

Here is my log4j.properties.

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG,console,File
```

## Console Appender

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] [%t %d{hh:mm:ss}] (%F:%M:%L) %m%n

## Rolling File Appender

log4j.appender.File=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.File.maxFileSize=10000KB
log4j.appender.File.maxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.File.File=C:/logs/Log.log
log4j.appender.File.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.File.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5p | %c | %t | %m%n
log4j.appender.File.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.File.Append=true

## Custom assignments

log4j.logger.endpoint=DEBUG,console,File
log4j.logger.controller=DEBUG,console,File
log4j.logger.handler=DEBUG,console,File

## Disable additivity

log4j.additivity.endpoint=false
log4j.additivity.controller=false
log4j.additivity.handler=false
log4j.additivity.dao=false
log4j.additivity.loggingInterceptor=false

## Castor

log4j.category.org.exolab.castor=DEBUG,console,File

## Spring Framework

log4j.category.org.springframework=ALL,console,File
log4j.category.org.springframework.beans.factory=DEBUG,console,File

Can some one guide me with this?

Comment: Have you looked at the WebSphere SystemOut.log file when you first start up the application? There are usually log4j errors logged there if it tries to configure and fails. You also might try temporarily enabling `-Dlog4j.debug` for the JVM to get log4j's own startup to log extra information.

Comment: I did not see any log 4j config errors in the SysOut logs of WebSphere. I enabled Tracing, the strange thing is all the spring framework, castor logs are logged in trace.log of WebSphere. Any pointer from this? I appreciate your time

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're just missing the configuration file parameter you need to set in JVM:

> Servers > Application servers > [app server name] > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine

Than point Log4J configuration file:

> -Dlog4j.configuration=$POINT_TO_LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE

Comment: But wont this be set for all the app that gets deployed on the server. I'm looking for something at application level..

Comment: You don't need to do this. log4j.properties is the default. It just needs to be in your classpath.

Comment: the properties file is in the classpath. It is available under WEB-INF/classes folder.